# Using Sublime Text to send code to terminal

Tags: bash, r

I have just recently switched from Mac OS to Ubuntu and I am missing a specific feature (not Mac OS related) that I couldn't find anywhere.

I want to use Sublime Text 3 as a general code editor and use Ctrl+Enter to send code to terminal depending on the code used (e.g. if bash shell, send it to shell, if R, send it to R, etc.).

I have been trying the same route I used on Mac OS (with the packages R-Box, SublimeREPL and SendCode) but to no avail. I have found some tutorial using Terminus (https://bishwarup-paul.medium.com/a-guide-to-using-r-in-sublime-text-27f78b33f872) but this does not exactly fits my needs (the terminus window has to be configured each time and I can't seem to separate it from the current Sublime window).

Comment: The tool `sendcode`  you used with Sublime Text should also work on Linux. See the github page https://github.com/randy3k/SendCode

Comment: Thanks, I was missing `xdotool`.